# HighCharts within JQuery tabs

Tags: jquery, highcharts, jquery-tabs

I am having a strange problem while using HighCharts as ASPX user control within JQuery tabs.

All pages are derived from a Master page. JQuery tabs are working fine in all content pages but when I place my HighCharts user control withing tabs, blank page is displayed with no rendered HTML available (view source). When I remove tabs, charts are working fine as well.

Here is the code:

```
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#tabs").tabs();
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Chart</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
            <div>
                <control:Chart ID="ChartData" runat="server"></control:Chart>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

This is driving me nuts. Any help is appreciated.

Best Regards,
Faisal

Comment: Can you provide some example or fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with [IE](http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=18375). The link gives a workaround that is a bit cumbersome.